# In windowsphone 8/8.1 Silverlight, is it possible to distinguish, if the app is closed by user or is terminated in background

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have a requirement where in if the windows phone app is terminated in background, i want to show the same page where the user left, when the app is launched again.

However if user closes the app, i have to show the login page.

Is it possible that a windows phone silverlight app terminates in background, due to OS resource requirements, similar to windows tablet apps ? i never saw a windows phone silverlight app getting terminated in background, what i can see that a max of 7-8 recent apps are displayed when we long press on the back button. even if my  app is not not there in the recent list it gets resumed to the same page and i get the event IsApplicationInstancePreserved as true.

However there seems to be no way to identify if the app is terminated by OS, so that i can navigate to the same page where user was previously.

There are two ways of closing a windows phone app
1) press the back button on the first page , in this case the closing event is fired.
2) Long press the back button and close your apps in the recent app list, when user does a long press and closes, the deactivated event is fired.
When user presses the windows button the deactivated event is fired and app goes in background.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is terminated/closed in the background then when you launch the app then in the launch method **OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)** args has this property called  PreviousExecutionState which is Enum of type ApplicationExecutionState and has the following values:

```
public enum ApplicationExecutionState
{
    NotRunning = 0,
    Running = 1,
    Suspended = 2,
    Terminated = 3,
    ClosedByUser = 4,
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am not able to use this event in windows phone 8.1 silverlight app. I am not able to override this method OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args) , however i able to see LaunchActivatedEventArgs by going to its definition

Comment: App.xaml.cs has a default implementation of this method you don't have to explicitly override.Or the method Name is OnLaunched in your case. In that method only you can perform certain action based on he ApplicationExecutionState

Comment: I do not see the default implementation , when i create a project in visual studio for windows phone 8.1 silverlight

Comment: Ok. Launch method args doesn't have ApplicationExecutionState in WP8.1 silverlight its only present IActivatedEventArgs which is contract activated method.

Comment: So is there a possibility to check in windows phone 8 silverlight project?

Comment: Didn't check in that. But I think it would mostly be same for both WP8 and WP8.1. What I have mentioned is for WP8.1 store apps

Comment: It is not the same unlike wp8.1 store apps